# Function does not return the JSON result when invoked

Tags: json, node.js, function

I am new to node.js and I wrote a code that invokes an API (GET) which returns a JSON array of documents. The GET works fine, the problem is that I can access the results inside the function but not from outside. The first alert inside the function display the JSON content fine, but I get an undefined value on the second alert.(result) which is outside the function.
This is my piece of code:

```
function getNames(){
      $.get("./api/myapi")
          .done(function(data) {
              if(data.length > 0) {
                $('#databaseNames').html("Database contents: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                var mylist2 = JSON.stringify(data);
                alert (mylist2);  // This alert is fine
                return (mylist2);

              }
          });
      }

  var result = getNames() ;
  alert (result);   // Here I get "undefined".
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use callback functions to use the result. As javascript is asynchronous in nature It will not be blocked by the api call. Modify the code a little bit like this..

```
  function getNames(cb){
      $.get("./api/myapi")
          .done(function(data) {
              if(data.length > 0) {
                $('#databaseNames').html("Database contents: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                var mylist2 = JSON.stringify(data);
                cb(mylist2);
              }
          });
      };

  getNames(function(res){
          alert(res);
  //Other functions with the result //
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the proposed code but the function getNames is not invoked. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I made a slight mistake. I have modified the code. Please let me know if it is working.